# Regex para cores hexadecimais

Tags: string, regex, python-2.7

Eu tenho uma pequena dúvida: eu tenho uma regex que captura em 3 grupos(2 valores por grupo) de determinada cor, mas isso quando eu tenho 6 valores(excluindo o #), eu gostaria de saber como implementar para pegar **1** grupo quando a cor for por exemplo: `#333` e **3** grupos quando for por exemplo `#628F61`?

**Exemplo 1**

Por exemplo, o usuário inseriu:

```
#fff
```

e a regex retorna **1** grupo com:

```
fff
```

**Exemplo 2**

inseriu:

```
#F00000
```

retorna **3** grupos:

1. `F0`
2. `00`
3. `00`

Até agora eu fiz isso:

```
#?(\w{2})(\w{2})(\w{2})
```

Comment: Um *if* que verifica o comprimento da *string* não resolve não?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Para atender à pergunta, eis a versão com *regex*:**

```
#?(([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})|([0-9a-f])([0-9a-f])([0-9a-f]))
```

Este  Regex separa por 3 grupos de dois caracteres hexa, ou 3 grupos de um caractere hexa cada.

Pra aproveitar a saída sem muita complexidade, você pode concatenar os grupos 2 e 5, 3 e 6, 4 e 7 respectivamente, pois apenas um de cada par estará preenchido.

```
#?(([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})|([0-9a-f]{3}))
```

Esta é a "original" da pergunta, com 3 ou 1 grupo.

**Versão simples e direta sem *regex*:**

Pra esse tipo de problema, acho que o *regex* apesar de aparentar ser mais curto, é de uma complexidade desnecessária, tanto pra ser processado quanto pra ser debugado, então resolvi colocar esse exemplo básico usando programação "tradicional".

Funciona com ou sem `#` no começo, e com 3 ou 6 dígitos.

```
color = "#bacc01"

if color[0]=="#":
   color = color[1:]

if len(color) == 3:
   r = color[0]
   g = color[1]
   b = color[2]

else:
   r = color[0:2]
   g = color[2:4]
   b = color[4:6]

print( "red  ", r )
print( "green", g )
print( "blue ", b )
```

Saída:

```
red   ba
green cc
blue  01
```

Pra adaptar pra #abc sair em um grupo só, basta trocar o que for dentro do `if` inicial.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! +1

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai a expressão:

```
^#((\w{2})(\w{2})(\w{2})|(\w{3}))$
```

Basicamente adicionei uma nova condição para o caso de 3 caracteres, e também um `$`, indicando que a string deve acabar ali.

Como um bônus, aqui vai uma expressão para detectar uma string de cores com 3 ou 6 caracteres (mas sem pegar os 3 grupos):

```
^#(?:[0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}$
```

Answer (score 1):

**Essa expressão deve funcionar em seu caso:**

```
^#?([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})|([0-9a-fA-F]{3})$
```

Irá retornar **um** grupo para cores como `#fff` `333` `#333`. Ou senão, irá retornar **três** grupos para cores como `#ffffff` `ff33FF` `#333333`.

Note também que a expressão possui o caractere `^` no início da linha e o `$` no final, fica à sua disposição removê-los. Nessa expressão são aceitos somente caracteres hexadecimais e o `#` é opcional.